# Configuring what happens when you start an AWS EC2 instance (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've set up an EC2 instance for cloud gaming. The instance runs Windows Server 2019 and everything works well, except that every time I start the instance I have to RDP in to start Parsec, the program I use when playing games.

I've configured Parsec to start when Windows starts, but I need to log in (via) RDP once I'm starting the instance from a stopped state to get Parsec running. Is there a way I can tell EC2 "hey, when you start this EC2 instance, I want you to log in (so my "run on startup" programs start)"? Or is there a way to generally say "please start this program and run this service (e.g. Windows Audio Service) when this instance starts"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do this. First and easiest one: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/downloads/autologon

To set up:

1. Log in to EC2 instance via RDP. Download the tool, run it. Enter the username and password of the user you want to auto login to Windows as.

If you're using Parsec, make sure you configure Parsec to start when windows starts (System Tray -> Right Click -> Run when computer starts

Alternatively, looks like [EC2 Launch V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch-v2-overview.html) can do this. Parsec actually has a tool for this as well: https://github.com/parsec-cloud/Parsec-Cloud-Preparation-Tool.

Comment: you totally saved my arse.  I have ansible running, and some harden script that runs and sets some run once stuff, and i need the run once stuff to be handled automatic.  the autologin was what i was looking for all day.  ansible autologin doesnt come up unless you type it in exactly.  i was looking for anyway to login with ansible ,or fire run once automatically.  Thanks!